# Plaid: Plaid.create is stuck onLoading

Tags: javascript, plaid

I am integrating with Plaid using vanilla javascript. I am able to get the link_token in order to create the Plaid platform using Plaid.create({...}). However, I am running into this weird bug where Plaid.create({...}) is stuck on loading state without ever resolving into onSuccess. When `handler.open()` is initiated, the plaid interface comes out but both usernames and password are saying invalid credentials (i am guessing this is due to the missing onSuccess call). Here is the code snippet (there are no console errors, just the console message from onLoad): Can anybody help me figure this out? Thank you!

```
 function syncUpWithPlaid(token) {
  const handler = Plaid.create({
    token,
    onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {
      console.log('success!', public_token)
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/tracking/access-token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          public_token: public_token,
          accounts: metadata.accounts,
          institution: metadata.institution,
          link_session_id: metadata.link_session_id,
        },
      });
    },
    onLoad: () => {
      console.log('loading') // for some reason it is stuck here
    },
    onExit: (err, metadata) => {
      console.log('err', err);
    },
    onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {
      console.log('eventName', eventName)
      console.log('metadata', metadata)
    },
  });
  handler.open();
}
```

Comment: onSuccess is not showing up is because your credentials are wrong, not the other way around. Can you confirm that you are using the Sandbox environment? If so, what Sandbox credentials are you using?

Comment: Thanks Alex! Yes you were right i completely misunderstood the integration flow aha